# For loop sum of numbers between two numbers

Tags: c, for-loop

I need to create a program that get's the sum of numbers from 100 to 500.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <10; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

It should print 55 (the sum of numbers between 1 and 10), but it prints out 136101521283645.

After this I need a program that gets the sum of numbers from 100 to 500.

Comment: try `printf("%d\n", sum)` or put the `printf`-statement outside of the loop.

Comment: Where is your printf statement

Comment: This will give you the sum of 1 to 9.

Comment: and you know.. there is a better way to calculate this sum (hint: sum of arithmetic series).

Comment: Sum `a..b` (where `a <= b`) is `(a + b) * (b - a + 1) / 2`. No loop required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are only doing the sum for i from 1 to 9, and you print that sum every loop.

Instead, you should do this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

For 100 to 500, do that:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 100; i <= 500; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as a response to make your question solved.

Comment: Please read basic examples on how to use scanf and similar functions. I think you just did not searched at all for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Put `printf` outside the loop

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <10; i++)
{
  sum = sum + i;
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change it so it prints the final sum !

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <10; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}
 printf("%d", sum);
```

so your final program (sum from 100 to 500) will be this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 100; i <500; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}
 printf("%d", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your print statement outside of your loop. It's printing every result every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do that is the following:
here its the program:

```
public class unoQuini {
    private int sum = 0;
    private static int menor = 1;
    private static int mayor = 5;
    public int getSum() {
      return sum;
    }
    public void setSum(int sum) {
      this.sum = sum;
    }
    public int getMenor() {
      return menor;
    }
    public void setMenor(int menor) {
      this.menor = menor;
    }
    public int getMayor() {
      return mayor;
    }
    public void setMayor(int mayor) {
      this.mayor = mayor;
    }
    public static void main (String Args[]){
      unoQuini unqui = new unoQuini(); 
      int sum2 = 0;
      for (int i = menor; i<= mayor;i++ ){
        sum2 += i;
        unqui.setSum(sum2);
      }
      System.out.println("Suma = "+ unqui.getSum());
    }
}
```

the important part is:

```
public static void main (String Args[]){
          unoQuini unqui = new unoQuini(); 
          int sum2 = 0;
          for (int i = menor; i<= mayor;i++ ){
            sum2 += i;
            unqui.setSum(sum2);
          }
          System.out.println("Suma = "+ unqui.getSum());
        }
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like Java code, the op wanted a `C` solution.

Comment: This looks like an unrelated answer. Have you pasted it into the wrong window?

Comment: Sorry I did it in Java

Answer (score 0):

firs of all, u r excluding 10(TO number), also, u r printing numbers inside the  for loop

```
int SumOfNumbers(int from, int to)
{
    int sum;
    if(from > to)
    {
       sum = from;
       from = to;
       to = sum
    }
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = from; i <= to; ++i)
       sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

then u just can call ur func

```
sum = SumOfNumbers(from, to);
printf("%d\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Print the sum of First n Natural Number
```

## include <stdio.h>

int main () {

```
int n;
printf("Enter The Natural Number : ");
scanf("%d \n", n);

int sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}

printf("Sum is : %d \n", sum);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).